# Size of a file in the FAT system

Tags: fat

I know that in recent file systems as EXT the i-node contains the actual size of the file. So if I want to know the size of a file I just need to read the meta-data.

How is this done in the FAT system (since there aren't i-nodes)? Do the OS need to go through all the blocks that contains the file and sum the size of each one?

Answer (score 1):

[If we look at the layout](http://www.tavi.co.uk/phobos/fat.html), we can see that each entry in the table has a **Starting Cluster** and **File Size in Bytes**.

[FAT32's Records contain the same data](https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html).